# Bind a WPF Button directly to another Element's Method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm attempting to create a WPF button that will increase the date in a DatePicker control directly without using a click event handler in the code behind.

I have extended the DatePicker class as so, which works as expected if used in the code behind:

```
public class ChronicleDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public void IncreaseDay()
    {
        SelectedDate = SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

And am attempting to use the following binding in my XAML, however I'm unable to get it to work:

```
<local:ChronicleDatePicker x:Name="dtWorkingDayPicker" SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" />
<Button Command="{Binding IncreaseDay}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dtWorkingDayPicker}">Boop</Button>
```

I've also tried the following:

```
Command="{Binding ElementName=dtWorkingDayPicker, Path=IncreaseDay}"
```

and

```
Click="{Binding ElementName=dtWorkingDayPicker, Path=IncreaseDay}"
```

But no luck! Google isn't being kind to me today either.

Appreciate any help that anyone can give! Thanks

EDIT:
Thanks for the constructive criticism and suggestions- to clarify I'm not specifically trying to avoid C#, just trying to avoid too much code in the XAML CS file and learn a bit more about binding. Admittedly I believed what I was trying to achieve was a bit simpler than it is and it probably makes sense to keep the code in my view model as opposed to trying to do it purely in XAML.

I appreciate the code that people have provided, it has helped to increase my understanding of how binding works in WPF.

Comment: Binding works on properties, not on methods.

Comment: Create an attached dependency property/behaviour and increment in there.

Comment: You're barking up the wrong tree. The `Command` property has to be bound to an `ICommand` instance value. The `Click` property has to be set to some actual method, i.e. the event handler. It's not clear why you are trying to avoid code-behind or C# code. An `ICommand` that directly updates the view model would be appropriate. Since you haven't provided a good [mcve] that shows clearly how your current code looks, there's no good way to answer your question (and there are lots of bad ways to do so...see the one answer you've gotten so far, using an attached property which IMHO is overkill).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code is correct except for following:
Modify your ChronicleDatePicker class as follows:

```
internal class ChronicleDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    Command cmd = new Command();
    public ICommand IncreaseDay
    {
        get
        {
            return cmd;
        }
    }
}

class Command :ICommand
{

    internal DateTime? selectedDate = null;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var picker = ((ChronicleDatePicker)parameter);
        picker.SelectedDate = picker.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

*You should return `ICommand` from your IncreaseDay property, because  binding property of Button Command should return `ICommand`*

And small change in .xaml

1) Add Element name in Button command as

Command="{Binding IncreaseDay, **ElementName=dtWorkingDayPicker**}"

*Because you have to tell `IncreaseDay` is present in which `class`*

Answer (score 1):

To bind a command you need a property implementing the [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx). It is not possible to bind directly to a method. There are several ways to solve your problem ... here is one possible solution:

You can create an attached property to *connect* a `Button` with a `DatePicker`. You can find a introduction at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx). Here is a possible implementation:

```
public static class ButtonProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IncreaseDatePickerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IncreaseDatePicker",
            typeof(DatePicker),
            typeof(ButtonProperties),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(IncreaseDatePickerPropertyChanged));

    public static DatePicker GetIncreaseDatePicker(Button b)
    {
        return (DatePicker)b.GetValue(IncreaseDatePickerProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIncreaseDatePicker(Button b, DatePicker value)
    {
        b.SetValue(IncreaseDatePickerProperty, value);
    }

    private static void IncreaseDatePickerPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Click -= B_Click;
        b.Click += B_Click;
    }

    private static void B_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker picker = GetIncreaseDatePicker((Button)sender);
        picker.SelectedDate = picker.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

Use the property like:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="picker"/>
<Button Content="Increase" local:ButtonProperties.IncreaseDatePicker="{Binding ElementName=picker}"/>
```